# Why does C allow implicit casting from const to non-const pointers

Tags: c, pointers, casting, constants, implicit

The following code:

```
  const char * p;
  char * i = p;
```

does not compile in CPP.

> error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*

However, there are no compilation errors when compiling as C code.
**Why does C allow implicit casting of a const pointer to a non const pointer?**

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages with their own rules and semantics (despite a somewhat similar syntax). Const-correctness is one area where they differ.

Comment: MSVC complains: *warning C4090: 'initializing': different 'const' qualifiers*

Comment: They are indeed different. But this behavior renders the const keyword useless in this scenario...

Comment: Your C compiler didn't give you a warning? MSVC and `gcc` both issue warnings.

Comment: How did you compile? C has a long and rich history. Some compilers aren't strict by default, because that would break old code. You may need to tell it explicitly. In a GCC like compilers that would be with a `-pedantic` flag.

Comment: Yes, I see a warning but not an error like I would expect. My question is why is there no error?

Comment: @DM - It's still standard conforming. The standard doesn't say that a constraint violation must result in compilation terminating. All it says is that the compiler must issue a diagnostic. A warning is a diagnostic. An implementation is free to continue translating the program, as though it offered an extension. If you prefer not to do that, you can use something like the `-pedantic-errors` flag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Although there are some minor differences, this code is illegal in both languages

Answer (score 0):

C has a concept of the Undefined Behaviour. It allows it to compile programs even if compiler is noticing the possibility of the UB. In many cases warning is omitted.

In this  case (gcc)

```
warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Q8CHgU